# #Wordpress How to run contact form 7 select filter conditionally

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a one page where I am showing job openings and another one is job detail page. Here am using only one form built using contact form 7. On job listing page I have displayed the select dropdown for selecting the role on job listing page and on detail page displayed the role as readonly in textbox on which job u selected.

But the problem is that I want to add the validation on not selecting the role from the dropdown on job listing page, but if I add the validation using filter directly then on job details page is showing error and I do not want to show the drop down there.

I have added the validation conditional wise but the form gets submitted without any error on not selecting the role from the drop down.

Here is my code

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_select',static function ($result, $tag) {
    if(is_page('careers')){
        $result = wpharvest_custom_validation_select($result, $tag);
    }
    return $result;
},
'wpharvest_custom_validation_select'
, 20, 2 );
// my function
function wpharvest_custom_validation_select( $result, $tag ) {
        $roleType = isset( $_POST['role'] ) ? trim( $_POST['role'] ) : '';
        if($roleType == '') {
            if ( 'role' == $tag->name && empty( $_POST['role'] ) ) {
                $result->invalidate($tag, "This field is required.");
            }
        }
        return $result;
}
```

Comment: Just use - Conditional Fields for Contact Form 7 plugin ? Or follow this doc - https://contactform7.com/2015/03/28/custom-validation/ . Another example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55586914/custom-validation-message-for-select-field-in-contact-form-7-wordpress